# Liveness probe failures not removing the pod ip from the service endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, probe

I have a deployment with 2 replicas of Nginx. It has only the liveness probe to monitor the health of the service. Due to high traffic, my liveness probe fails, the Nginx container is restarted, but the pod status running state and Pod condition is Ready. Due to that POD, IP is not removed the service endpoint and request were send to restarting pod which results in some failures.

Answer (score 1):

As per [container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes):

> - `livenessProbe`: Indicates whether the Container is running. If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the Container, and the
>     Container is subjected to its restart policy [...]
> - `readinessProbe`: Indicates whether the Container is ready to service requests. **If the readiness probe fails, the endpoints
>     controller removes the Pod’s IP address from the endpoints of all
>     Services** that match the Pod [...]

You need to [add a readinessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) to grant that the endpoints of unhealthy containers will be removed.

> Readiness probes are configured similarly to liveness probes. The only
>   difference is that you use the `readinessProbe` field instead of the
>   `livenessProbe` field.

Comment: Thanks, @Eduardo for the clarification.  That means if I don't have a readiness probe, there may be a chance to send the requests to the container is undergoing the restart due to the liveness probe failures and that results in request failures. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Rakesh it's correct. Ideally, you should have both `liveness` and `readiness` probes configured.